# no puedo obtener el valor de un elemento para pasarlo a mi funcion

Tags: javascript, html

muy buenas, estoy tratando de obtener el valor de un elemento tipo , para pasarlo a otra funcion.

```
<input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Buscar" 
onclick="editData(document.getElementById(nombre).value)" >
```

Pero obtengo este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: cuando doy click quiero obtener el value de otro elemento que no es el boton que estoy clickeando, entiendo que si quiero el value del mismo elemento utilizo (this.value), pero quiero el valor de otro elemento hermano

Comment: <div class="form-group col-md-2 mx-auto" >
  <label for="estacion" >Número de Pedido</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero"  style="text-align: center" required>
 </div>

 <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="editData(document.getElementById('nombre').value)" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observaciones**

- Una cosa es definir a la función y otra muy diferente es invocarla, veo que en el HTML estás llamando a x función, pero la creación de la misma no aparece.
- Entonces deberías tener un segmento donde tengas el script y la composición de esta misma función con la o las acciones que va a realizar con el parámetro esperado.
- Además de que el elemento que pasas como id debe ir como string entre comillas

Así debería quedar:

```html
    <input id="nombre" type="text" value="1">
    
    <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Buscar" 
    onclick="editData(document.getElementById('nombre').value)" >
    
    <script>
      function editData (elemento) {
        console.log(elemento);
      }
    </script>
```

Por otro lado considero que deberías separar las acciones  a realizar y obtener los elementos HTML por ejemplo por medio de su id, agregar un listener al evento deseado y entonces ahora si obtener el texto del atributo value del elemento deseado.

```html
    <input id="elemento" type="text" value="1" />
    <input id="nombre" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Buscar" />
    
    <script>
      let nombreInput  = document.getElementById('nombre');
      let otroElemento = document.getElementById('elemento'); 
      
      nombreInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(otroElemento.value);
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El único error que percibo es que falta colocar **nombre** dentro de comillas:

```
<input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Buscar" 
onclick="editData(document.getElementById('nombre').value)" >
```

Comment: eso va a generar un error

Comment: @DavElsanto :) cierto, es comilla simple